# Android: Intent setClass causes NullPointer exception

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I want use Intent from TcpClient go to PreCamera. It 's causes java.lang.NullPointer Exception.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Log.v("Pic", "context");
intent.setClass(TcpClient.this, PreCamera.class);
Log.v("Pic", "ok");
this.mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

this is TcpClient construct:

```
public TcpClient(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

This is the Exception information:

```
12-08 10:56:53.515: V/Pic(2579): context
12-08 10:56:53.519: W/dalvikvm(2579): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
12-08 10:56:53.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2579): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14
12-08 10:56:53.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2579): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 10:56:53.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
12-08 10:56:53.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
12-08 10:56:53.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.content.Intent.setClass(Intent.java:4920)
12-08 10:56:53.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at com.Image.Collect.TcpClient.takePic(TcpClient.java:330)
12-08 10:56:53.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at com.Image.Collect.TcpClient.commandExecute(TcpClient.java:467)
12-08 10:56:53.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at com.Image.Collect.TcpClient.receive(TcpClient.java:278)
12-08 10:56:53.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at com.Image.Collect.TcpClient.talk(TcpClient.java:179)
12-08 10:56:53.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at com.Image.Collect.InfoCollect$6.run(InfoCollect.java:303)
12-08 10:56:53.539: E/InfoCollect(2579): onPause
```

this is some AndroidMainfest.xml information:

```
 <activity android:name=".TcpClient"
                 ... (other info)
        </activity>
 <activity android:name=".PreCamera"
                ... (other info)
        </activity>
```

The API is level 8.

When I try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TcpClient.this, PreCamera.class);
```

it causes:

```
12-08 11:31:45.221: W/dalvikvm(2805): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
12-08 11:31:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2805): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14
12-08 11:31:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2805): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 11:31:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2805):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
12-08 11:31:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2805):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
```

I see someone say this is because I init mContext is too early, It should be init after OnCreate() method or later. But how to init after this method? I'm a beginner of Android Dev.

TcpClient is extends Activity. I use:

```
mContext = this;
Intent intent = new Intent(TcpClient.this, PreCamera.class);
```

it is not woking well.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this instead...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TcpClient.this, PreCamera.class);


this.mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching PreCamera activity from TcpClient activity:
Try this

```
TcpClient.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Changed because TcpClient extends Activity:

What about simply this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreCamera.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Your other way of doing it would work, it just takes more code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, PreCamera.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: TcpClient is extends Activity